# Any C library available to interact with an Ethereum smart contract?

Tags: library

I need a C library that enables to create, sign transactions and interact with the smart contract.

Comment: Well, you could always do everything in a NodeJS script (which takes input arguments if needed), and then execute it as a process from your C program.

Answer (score 0):

[libethc](https://github.com/mhw0/libethc) does the job, except networking (for now). You can encode/decode and sign transactions with it.